# React Native - Navigating between different stacks in drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a kind of complex navigation architecture with a Drawer Navigation at the top after a login (handled through a switchNavigator).

something like this -

DrawerNavigator ->

- DashboardStack

  - Dashboard Screen
  - Search Screen
- ProjectStack

  - ProjectsList Screen
  - RecordsList Screen
  - RecordDetails Screen

So to search for a record, I go to my search screen (Level 2 of DashboardStack). I search a record, receive a list from backend and then show a list of them. On clicking an item in the list, I need to reach the RecordDetailsScreen with the relevant props (Level 3 of ProjectStack).

This is currently working for me, but when a user presses the back button on android or swipes back on iOS, react-navigation's default behaviour takes me back to the start of my current stack, i.e. ProjectsList Screen (Level 1 of ProjectStack). While, as an end user, I would have expected it to go to the SearchScreen.

I am using react-navigation: 4.1.1 in my project.

Any leads on how I can remember the previous screen from where I came to the present screen would be great.

PS - needless to say, I have other ways to get to the RecordDetailsScreen as well (so cannot default the behaviour to go back to the SearchScreen).

Comment: How you are currently navigate from search to record details screen?

Comment: @SaachiTech

this.props.navigation.navigate('RecordDetailsScreen', {props})